# Удаление файлов в каталогах и подкаталогах старше определенной даты последнего изменения

Tags: c#, winforms

Уважаемые эксперты, помогите  разобраться.
Есть OpenBrowserDialog через него выбираем корневой каталог, в нем  содержатся подкаталоги с  тестовыми файлами.
Как организовать удаление всех файлов в подкаталогах которые старше определенной даты  последнего изменения? Можно ли установить дату визуально? Можно ли сделать  выбор диапазона который  не удалять, пример: удаляем все .txt файлы в каталогах  и подкаталогах кроме файлов  у которых дата последнего изменения (01.12.2019 - 31.12.2019).

Answer (score 1):

все это можно для выбора даты используйте MonthCalendar в ToolBox если делаете на WinForms 
вот пример поиска по папкам

список будет содержать пути ко всем найденным файлам

```
public List<string> Files = new List<string>();
```

метод для поиска во всех папках и под папках

```
   public void DirSearch(string sDir)
            {
                foreach (var f in Directory.GetFiles(sDir))
                {

                   Files.Add(f.ToLower());

                }
                foreach (var d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
                {   
                   DirSearch(d); 
                }    

            }
```

потом можете пройтись по списку с файлами и посмотреть какие файлы соответствуют вашим критерием и если надо удалить их

Comment: Какой-то костыльный метод для поиска всех файлов у Вас, конечно
```C#
foreach (var element in Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Games", null, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```

Comment: @LiptonDev Вы понимаете какой смысл имеет слово ''костыль'' ? , костыль  у вас вы явно указываете путь  `@"D:\Games"`  а метод рекурсивный но вы видимо этого не видите или не знаете о таком.

Comment: Спасибо Вам  обоим!

Comment: @OXYGEN А ничего, что я привел только пример как сделать без рекурсии? Вам что, религия запрещает поменять мой путь на свою переменную?

Comment: @LiptonDev судя по вашим комментариям вы пишете быстрее чем думаете что пишете. цитирую вас :`Какой-то костыльный метод для поиска всех файлов у Вас, конечно`, а после приводите пример с ''костылем'' `@"D:\Games"` где логика ?

Comment: @OXYGEN Извините, конечно, но я просто смеюсь с вас, можете объяснить, в чем костыль моего пути? В том, что вы не понимаете, что я просто привел пример поиска всех файлов без рекурсии? Или вы не понимаете, что мой код превращается в метод ровно за 5 секунд?

Comment: @LiptonDev я все хорошо понимаю , это вы не понимаете, вы используете слова - смысл которых вам не известен к **коду у меня вопросов нету** вот ссылочка вам почитать  http://lurkmore.to/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BB%D1%8C

Comment: @OXYGEN Хорошо, давайте я тогда Вам поясню почему ваш код - костыль.  1 - Рекурсия. 2 - готовая, встроенная функция поиска всех файлов во всех папках по заданному пути.  Исходя из этого задаю последний вопрос, для чего нужна рекурсия в вашем случае и чем она будет лучше?

Comment: @LiptonDev ты что то запрещенное принимаешь ? :))) Haskell полностью рекурсивный язык следуя твоей "логике" он костыльный :)  иди учи смысл слов а потом будешь объяснять мне что то , удали рекурсию из моего метода и поймешь зачем она там нужна!

Comment: @OXYGEN Хоспаде, я попросил объяснить зачем она нужна, а вы что-то про "запрещенное" мне говорите, я прекрасно понимаю зачем у вас рекурсия, но она там не нужна, если перегрузить метод...

Comment: @LiptonDev  к чему вы это `если перегрузить метод...:` просто смешно уже :) я вам больше скажу если написать другой метод то и перегружать не чего не надо будет:)

Comment: @OXYGEN Хорошо, я понял вас, не вижу смысла в дальнейшей дискуссии, изобретайте велосипеды дальше :)